# How do I loop through in table to send the value

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

Below is my HTML:

> ```
> 115px;">
>                       <div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="width: 115px;">€</div>
>                    </td>
>                    <td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 87px;">
>                       <div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 87px;"></div>
>                    </td>
>                    <td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 170px;">
>                       <div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: right; width: 170px;"><input type="text"
> ```
>
> class="v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right"
> style="width: 153px;" maxlength="12">
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> American Express OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> MasterCard OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> Visa Card OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> Diners Card OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> Japan Credit Bureau OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> China Union Pay OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> ALI PAY OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> ZALANDO
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> WE CHAT OFF
>
>
> €
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> BREUNINGER
>
>
> €
>
> ````
> This is what I am writting:
> ```
> Actual_Amount= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Actual
> ````
>
> Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input")))
>
> ```
> Actual_Amount.send_keys("0")
> Actual_Amount.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
> for A in Actual_Amount:
>     Actual_Amount.send_keys(A)
>     Actual_Amount.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
>
> #print("This is my actual amount :" + (str)Actual_Amount)
> Differnce= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH," //div[text()='Difference']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::td[5]/div[@class='v-table-cell-wrapper']"))).text
> Actual_Amount= Differnce
> print("This is my actual amount :" + Actual_Amount)
> ```
>
> **Can anybody please tell me whats the correct way ? thank you so much**

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: its just stuck at the actual level with zero value.. I want whole coloumn to be filled with zero

Comment: you can get an array of all <input>s using find_elements... then iterate.  (Only press enter on the last one...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the HTML that you have shared, you could iterate through the table like below :

**Code :**

```
i = 1
difference_amount= []
for a_amount in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Actual Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input"):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a_amount).perform()
    #ele_1= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"(//div[text()='Actual Amount']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::input)[{i}]")))
    time.sleep(.5)
    a_amount.send_keys('0')
    time.sleep(.5)
    a_amount.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(.5)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[text()='Difference']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::table/descendant::tr[{i}]/td[5]")))).perform()
    difference_amount.append(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//div[text()='Difference']/ancestor::div[@class='v-table-header-wrap']/following-sibling::div/descendant::table/descendant::tr[{i}]/td[5]"))).text.replace('-', ''))
    time.sleep(.5)
    i = i + 1
```